# How to force data.table to consider input as values, not column names?

Tags: r, data.table, binary-search

How can I make data.table understand, that the values are variables defined above and not the column names?

The line with the first comment sould return 0L, but returns all data contained in dt.

Reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(zip_from = c("1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000",
"1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000"), zip_to = c("1000", "1001",
"1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007", "1008", "1009"
), time_1 = c(0, 332.8, 332.8, 362.5, 504.9, 256.6, 446.4, 694.4,
723.4, 462.3), dist_1 = c(0, 3208, 3208, 3465.3, 4275.5, 2267.6,
4158.1, 5811.4, 8842.6, 4624.7), dist_2 = c(0, 3208, 3208, 3465.3,
4275.5, 2267.6, 4158.1, 5811.4, 8842.6, 4624.7), time_2 = c(0,
332.8, 332.8, 362.5, 504.9, 256.6, 446.4, 694.4, 723.4, 462.3
)), .Names = c("zip_from", "zip_to", "time_1", "dist_1", "dist_2",
"time_2"), sorted = c("zip_from", "zip_to"), class = c("data.table",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

zip_from <- "8153"
zip_to <- "9536"
dt[J(zip_from, zip_to), nomatch = 0L] # returns everything (Not OK)

a <- "8153"
b <- "9536"
dt[J(a, b), nomatch = 0L] # returns 0L (OK)
dt[J("8153", "9536"), nomatch = 0L] # returns 0L (OK)
```

Comment: do you really have to use the same names? if yes, then maybe `dt[J(get("zip_from", envir=.GlobalEnv), get("zip_to", envir=.GlobalEnv)), nomatch = 0L]`

Comment: In future versions ([when `..` prefix becomes available in i](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blame/master/NEWS.md#L134)) this will become more convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest approach would be use a different name for the variables you use. For example:

```
zip.from <- "8153"
zip.to <- "9536";
dt[J(zip.from, zip.to), nomatch = 0L]
##Empty data.table (0 rows) of 6 cols: zip_from,zip_to,time_1,dist_1,dist_2,time_2
```

To force data.table package to use the values from zip_from and zip_to variables instead of column names with the same names you can use the code suggested in the comment:

```
dt[J(get("zip_from", envir=.GlobalEnv), get("zip_to", envir=.GlobalEnv)), nomatch = 0L]
##Empty data.table (0 rows) of 6 cols: zip_from,zip_to,time_1,dist_1,dist_2,time_2
```